# change app home page to another page in the application

Tags: oracle-apex

i have an oracle apex application with a home page (page 0) ,
When user registers in the app, the app is redirect to page 0(home page) .
i want to change this page to (page 23)
When I am trying to do that by going to (Shared Component --> Users interface--> Home URL.)and change the url,I am redirecting to page 0(home page).
I tried to change the page number that the application redirect to it after loginin the authentication scheme, I redirect to page 0(home page) again.
I want to know in oracle apex where i can redirect a home page to another pahge.

Comment: "Home URL" *is* the place; it works OK for me (can't tell why it doesn't work for you). As of Page 0 as a homepage: that's rather poor choice. Page 0 is kind of "special", you shouldn't use it as a homepage (maybe that's why you're setting it to page 23?).

Comment: page 0 is an only  example

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely possible to set another page as homepage in APEX and the way you did it should be fine. But the issue probably is with your page 0.
Page 0 is the default "Global Page" in the application. Whatever is on the global page is displayed on all pages, that is probably why you're seeing it when accessing another page. You should avoid using page 0 as a "real" page in the application.
You can confirm what the global page is in Shared Component --> Users interface--> Global Page
I haven't tested it, but try setting a server side condition of "never" on everything that is on page 0 and test again to see if it works. Google "oracle APEX global page" for some more reading.

Comment: page 0 is an only example the home page is page 1

Comment: I would update my question then since page 0 is not a normal page and it guided both Littlefoot and me in the wrong direction.